# Android Studio 3.5 - Missing new Memory Settings option

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.4, android-studio-3.5

Android Studio 3.5 release notes:

```
Android Studio now notifies you if it detects that you could improve  
performance by increasing the maximum amount of RAM that your OS should  
allocate for Android Studio processes, such as the core IDE, Gradle daemon,  
and Kotlin daemon. You can either accept the recommended settings by   
clicking the action link in the notification, or you can adjust these   
settings manually by selecting File > Settings (or Android Studio >   
Preferences on macOS), and then finding the Memory Settings section under  
Appearance & Behavior > System Settings.
```

This is what I have:
[image]

Comment: Create a custom VMoption, after that restart it and see if it appears. Go to `Help` -> `Edit Custom VM option...`, create one and write this in it `-Xmx3072m` and 
`-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [android studio configuration page](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#adjusting_heap_size):

> If you use a 64-bit system that has at least 5 GB of RAM, you can also adjust the heap sizes for your project manually.

It may be that your system does not meet these requirements.